# Flink: Flink Streamer for Apache Ignite

Tags: java, jar, apache-flink, ignite, flink-streaming

I am trying to dump the data from flink to ignite cache using Flink-Streamer of Ignite `IgniteSink`. I want to run it on cluster and I am using Ignite Fabric 2.0.0 and Flink 1.1.3. All the supporting libs of flink streamer of Ignite are of version 2.0.0.

I am creating the runnable jar from eclipse with choosing the option `Export required libraries into generated jar`, but when I submit the jar file on cluster to run, it gives the following error stack

```
[sanket@01hw738457 flink-1.1.3]$ ./bin/flink run -m 192.168.140.53:6123 /home/sanket/workspace/flink_ignite_sink/flink_ignite_sink_extr.jar
Cluster configuration: Standalone cluster with JobManager at /192.168.140.53:6123
Using address 192.168.140.53:6123 to connect to JobManager.
JobManager web interface address http://192.168.140.53:8081
Starting execution of program

------------------------------------------------------------
The program finished with the following exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ignite/IgniteException
    at flink_ignite_sink.main(flink_ignite_sink.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:509)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:403)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:320)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:777)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1005)
    at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1048)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.IgniteException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

I also have included the jar file called ignite-core-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar which include the `IgniteException` class. What can be the reason for this error?

Comment: Check that ignite-core definitely in classpath. For that try to print out classpath for current classloader in flink_ignite_sink.main() method.

Comment: Can you confirm if the flink worker nodes also have Ignite-core jar in classpath. Alternatively can you run the job in local flink setup and confirm if you are facing the same error?